# Using FindOpenCV.cmake with libopencv2.3-dev

Tags: ros, opencv, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While installing ros-electric-desktop-full, I ran into a conflict of ros-electric-vision-opencv (through libopencv2.3-dev) with the default OpenCV in Ubuntu 11.10. In order to resolve the conflict, I manually installed libopencv2.3-dev, which removed Ubuntu's default OpenCV installation (libcv-dev, libcvaux-dev and libhighgui-dev). However, I found out that the FindOpenCV.cmake file that can be downloaded from the OpenCV website does not work with libopencv2.3-dev. It used to work with default Ubuntu OpenCV installation though. That FindOpenCV.cmake file looks for OpenCV libraries with very different names than those installed by libopencv2.3-dev. Is there a FindOpenCV.cmake file that works with 2.3.1 and may also be compatible with default Ubuntu installation (libcv, libcvaux, libhighgui)? This is definitely a show stopper.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11920/using-findopencv.cmake-with-libopencv2.3-dev/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-13**:
The conflict with the default Ubuntu cv libraries looks related to this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/2657/solve-conflict-between-ubuntu-libcv21-and-ros (with still no solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The conflict now seems to be resolved with the latest update to the debs:

```
sudo apt-get install libcv2.1 ros-electric-vision-opencv libopencv2.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcv2.1 is already the newest version.
libopencv2.3 is already the newest version.
ros-electric-vision-opencv is already the newest version.
```

Package: libopencv2.3   Version: 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty

Package: ros-electric-vision-opencv   Version: 1.6.8-s1321009674~natty

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1